# php : if $ is null hide a table

Tags: php, if-statement, woocommerce, html-table, conditional-statements

I  have this mail-template from Woocommerce,

```
<?php

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit;
}

$text_align = is_rtl() ? 'right' : 'left';

do_action( 'woocommerce_email_before_order_table', $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email ); ?>

<?php if ( ! $sent_to_admin ) : ?>
    <h2><?php printf( __( 'Order #%s', 'woocommerce' ), $order->get_order_number() ); ?></h2>
<?php else : ?>
    <h2><a class="link" href="<?php echo esc_url( admin_url( 'post.php?post=' . $order->get_id() . '&action=edit' ) ); ?>"><?php printf( __( 'Order #%s', 'woocommerce'), $order->get_order_number() ); ?></a> (<?php printf( '<time datetime="%s">%s</time>', date_i18n( 'c', strtotime( $order->get_date_created() ) ), date_i18n( wc_date_format(), strtotime( $order->get_date_created() ) ) ); ?>)</h2>
<?php endif; ?>

<table class="td" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="6" style="width: 100%; font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Roboto, Arial, sans-serif;" border="1">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="td" scope="col" style="text-align:<?php echo $text_align; ?>;"><?php _e( 'Product', 'woocommerce' ); ?></th>
            <th class="td" scope="col" style="text-align:<?php echo $text_align; ?>;"><?php _e( 'Quantity', 'woocommerce' ); ?></th>
            <th class="td" scope="col" style="text-align:<?php echo $text_align; ?>;"><?php _e( 'Price', 'woocommerce' ); ?></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php echo wc_get_email_order_items( $order, array(
            'show_sku'      => $sent_to_admin,
            'show_image'    => false,
            'image_size'    => array( 32, 32 ),
            'plain_text'    => $plain_text,
            'sent_to_admin' => $sent_to_admin,
        ) ); ?>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <?php
            if ( $totals = $order->get_order_item_totals() ) {
                $i = 0;
                foreach ( $totals as $total ) {
                    $i++;
                    ?><tr>
                        <th class="td" scope="row" colspan="2" style="text-align:<?php echo $text_align; ?>; <?php if ( $i === 1 ) echo 'border-top-width: 4px;'; ?>"><?php echo $total['label']; ?></th>
                        <td class="td" style="text-align:<?php echo $text_align; ?>; <?php if ( $i === 1 ) echo 'border-top-width: 4px;'; ?>"><?php echo $total['value']; ?></td>
                    </tr><?php
                }
            }
        ?>
    </tfoot>
</table>

<?php if ( ! $sent_to_admin ) : ?>

<h3 style="margin: 20px 0;"><?php _e( 'Additional Tour Information', 'citytours' ) ?></h3>

<table class="td" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="6" style="width: 108%; font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Roboto, Arial, sans-serif;" border="1">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="td" scope="col" style="text-align:<?php echo $text_align; ?>;"><?php _e( 'Product', 'woocommerce' ) ?></th>
            <th class="td" scope="col" style="text-align:<?php echo $text_align; ?>;"><?php echo esc_html__( 'Booking No', 'citytours' ) ?></th>
            <th class="td" scope="col" style="text-align:<?php echo $text_align; ?>;"><?php echo esc_html__( 'Date', 'citytours' ) ?></th>
            <th class="td" scope="col" style="text-align:<?php echo $text_align; ?>;"><?php echo esc_html__( 'Pin Code', 'citytours' ) ?></th>
            <th class="td" scope="col" style="text-align:<?php echo $text_align; ?>;"><?php echo esc_html__( 'Adults', 'citytours' ) ?></th>
            <th class="td" scope="col" style="text-align:<?php echo $text_align; ?>;"><?php echo esc_html__( 'Kids', 'citytours' ) ?></th>
        </tr>

    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php 
        global $wpdb;
        $items = $order->get_items(); 

        foreach ( $items as $item ) {
            $product_id = $item['product_id'];
            $hotel_tour_id = get_post_meta( $product_id, '_ct_post_id', true );

            if ( $hotel_tour_id ) { 
                $booking_info = $wpdb->get_row( 'SELECT A.booking_no, A.pin_code, A.date_from, A.total_adults, A.total_kids , B.post_content
                FROM ' . CT_ORDER_TABLE . ' as A INNER JOIN ' .wp_posts. ' AS B ON A.POST_ID = B.ID
                WHERE other = ' . $order->get_order_number(), ARRAY_A );
                $newDate = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($booking_info['date_from']));
                ?>
                <tr>
                    <th class="td" scope="col" style="text-align:<?php echo $text_align; ?>;"><?php echo $item['name'] ?></th>
                    <td class="td" scope="col" style="text-align:<?php echo $text_align; ?>;"><?php echo $booking_info['booking_no'] ?></td>
                    <td class="td" scope="col" style="text-align:<?php echo $text_align; ?>;"><?php echo $newDate ?></td>
                    <td class="td" scope="col" style="text-align:<?php echo $text_align; ?>;"><?php echo $booking_info['pin_code'] ?></td>
                    <td class="td" scope="col" style="text-align:<?php echo $text_align; ?>;"><?php echo $booking_info['total_adults'] ?></td>
                    <td class="td" scope="col" style="text-align:<?php echo $text_align; ?>;"><?php echo $booking_info['total_kids'] ?></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <th class="td" scope="col" style="text-align:<?php echo $text_align; ?>;"><?php echo esc_html__( 'Description', 'citytours' ) ?></th>
                <td class="td" scope="col" colspan="5" style="text-align:<?php echo $text_align; ?>;"><?php echo $booking_info['post_content'] ?></td>
                </tr>
                <?php
            }
        }
        ?>
    </tbody>

</table>


<?php endif; ?>

<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_email_after_order_table', $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email ); ?>
```

I added some custom-post-data but now I really need to hide "Additional Tour information" when my $booking_info is null because if there is none, the customer gets an empty table just with headers.

Answer (score 0):

The thing you should do is store all your html data from

```
<h3 style="margin: 20px 0;"><?php _e( 'Additional Tour Information','citytours' ) ?></h3>
```

to

```
</table>
```

Inside a php variable instead of flat displayed, and set a variable that says if you have data or not in your table, for example

```
$content_filled = 0; // says you havent parsed your array so far

$table = '<h3 style="margin: 20px 0;"><?php _e( 'Additional Tour Information','citytours' ) ?></h3>';
```

/* some code here*/

```
$content_filled = 1; // says now you parsed your array
$table  .='<tr>
                    <th class="td" scope="col" style="text-align:'.$text_align'.>'.$item['name'].'</th>
                    <td class="td" scope="col" style="text-align:'.$text_align'.">'.$booking_info['booking_no'].'</td>';
```

and then you do at the end a

```
if($content_filled)
    echo $table;
```

Comment: There's no need to store all of the output in a string especially since WordPress  and woocommerce usually don't.  Much better to keep everything consistent rather than use two different techniques in one script.

Comment: well I never said to do it for all the output, I just said for the block that is wanted to be hidden if empty. We could also hide it in js but it would be more dirty and less efficient. If you have a better solution, feel free to post it and I ll upvote you!

Answer (score 0):

Without having to rewrite too much, the simplest, albeit not too elegant fix, would be to use the output buffer:

```
<?php

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit;
}

$text_align = is_rtl() ? 'right' : 'left';

do_action( 'woocommerce_email_before_order_table', $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email ); ?>

<?php if ( ! $sent_to_admin ) : ?>
    <h2><?php printf( __( 'Order #%s', 'woocommerce' ), $order->get_order_number() ); ?></h2>
<?php else : ?>
    <h2><a class="link" href="<?php echo esc_url( admin_url( 'post.php?post=' . $order->get_id() . '&action=edit' ) ); ?>"><?php printf( __( 'Order #%s', 'woocommerce'), $order->get_order_number() ); ?></a> (<?php printf( '<time datetime="%s">%s</time>', date_i18n( 'c', strtotime( $order->get_date_created() ) ), date_i18n( wc_date_format(), strtotime( $order->get_date_created() ) ) ); ?>)</h2>
<?php endif; ?>

<table class="td" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="6" style="width: 100%; font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Roboto, Arial, sans-serif;" border="1">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="td" scope="col" style="text-align:<?php echo $text_align; ?>;"><?php _e( 'Product', 'woocommerce' ); ?></th>
            <th class="td" scope="col" style="text-align:<?php echo $text_align; ?>;"><?php _e( 'Quantity', 'woocommerce' ); ?></th>
            <th class="td" scope="col" style="text-align:<?php echo $text_align; ?>;"><?php _e( 'Price', 'woocommerce' ); ?></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php echo wc_get_email_order_items( $order, array(
            'show_sku'      => $sent_to_admin,
            'show_image'    => false,
            'image_size'    => array( 32, 32 ),
            'plain_text'    => $plain_text,
            'sent_to_admin' => $sent_to_admin,
        ) ); ?>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <?php
            if ( $totals = $order->get_order_item_totals() ) {
                $i = 0;
                foreach ( $totals as $total ) {
                    $i++;
                    ?><tr>
                        <th class="td" scope="row" colspan="2" style="text-align:<?php echo $text_align; ?>; <?php if ( $i === 1 ) echo 'border-top-width: 4px;'; ?>"><?php echo $total['label']; ?></th>
                        <td class="td" style="text-align:<?php echo $text_align; ?>; <?php if ( $i === 1 ) echo 'border-top-width: 4px;'; ?>"><?php echo $total['value']; ?></td>
                    </tr><?php
                }
            }
        ?>
    </tfoot>
</table>

<?php if ( ! $sent_to_admin ) : ?>

<?php ob_start(); ?>

<h3 style="margin: 20px 0;"><?php _e( 'Additional Tour Information', 'citytours' ) ?></h3>

<table class="td" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="6" style="width: 108%; font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Roboto, Arial, sans-serif;" border="1">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="td" scope="col" style="text-align:<?php echo $text_align; ?>;"><?php _e( 'Product', 'woocommerce' ) ?></th>
            <th class="td" scope="col" style="text-align:<?php echo $text_align; ?>;"><?php echo esc_html__( 'Booking No', 'citytours' ) ?></th>
            <th class="td" scope="col" style="text-align:<?php echo $text_align; ?>;"><?php echo esc_html__( 'Date', 'citytours' ) ?></th>
            <th class="td" scope="col" style="text-align:<?php echo $text_align; ?>;"><?php echo esc_html__( 'Pin Code', 'citytours' ) ?></th>
            <th class="td" scope="col" style="text-align:<?php echo $text_align; ?>;"><?php echo esc_html__( 'Adults', 'citytours' ) ?></th>
            <th class="td" scope="col" style="text-align:<?php echo $text_align; ?>;"><?php echo esc_html__( 'Kids', 'citytours' ) ?></th>
        </tr>

    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php 
        global $wpdb;
        $items = $order->get_items(); 

        foreach ( $items as $item ) {
            $product_id = $item['product_id'];
            $hotel_tour_id = get_post_meta( $product_id, '_ct_post_id', true );

            if ( $hotel_tour_id ) { 
                $booking_info = $wpdb->get_row( 'SELECT A.booking_no, A.pin_code, A.date_from, A.total_adults, A.total_kids , B.post_content
                FROM ' . CT_ORDER_TABLE . ' as A INNER JOIN ' .wp_posts. ' AS B ON A.POST_ID = B.ID
                WHERE other = ' . $order->get_order_number(), ARRAY_A );
                $newDate = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($booking_info['date_from']));
                ?>
                <tr>
                    <th class="td" scope="col" style="text-align:<?php echo $text_align; ?>;"><?php echo $item['name'] ?></th>
                    <td class="td" scope="col" style="text-align:<?php echo $text_align; ?>;"><?php echo $booking_info['booking_no'] ?></td>
                    <td class="td" scope="col" style="text-align:<?php echo $text_align; ?>;"><?php echo $newDate ?></td>
                    <td class="td" scope="col" style="text-align:<?php echo $text_align; ?>;"><?php echo $booking_info['pin_code'] ?></td>
                    <td class="td" scope="col" style="text-align:<?php echo $text_align; ?>;"><?php echo $booking_info['total_adults'] ?></td>
                    <td class="td" scope="col" style="text-align:<?php echo $text_align; ?>;"><?php echo $booking_info['total_kids'] ?></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <th class="td" scope="col" style="text-align:<?php echo $text_align; ?>;"><?php echo esc_html__( 'Description', 'citytours' ) ?></th>
                <td class="td" scope="col" colspan="5" style="text-align:<?php echo $text_align; ?>;"><?php echo $booking_info['post_content'] ?></td>
                </tr>
                <?php
            }
        }
        ?>
    </tbody>

</table>

<?php 

$output = ob_get_clean();

if(isset($booking_info)){
    echo $output;
}?>

<?php endif; ?>

<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_email_after_order_table', $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email ); ?>
```